# In Docker Application in the ".Net Core 2.0 Version"

Tags: docker

I will develop in the database Application based on the .Net FrameWork Project I will Convert in  the .Net Core based Code Got No error.But Running Time got this Error Can need solution to Fix the Error.

> Could not load type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' from assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OleDbParameter is not available in .NET core yet.

refer this link to check compatible .net framework/runtime are supported

[image]

Comment: Can u Please Share the Link for reference purpose

Comment: use this link   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: If there is any alternative way in the .Net Framework oledb Supports in the .Net Core Version

Comment: you can try with mono runtime.. because mono runtime support OleDbParameter.   
 you can get that docker  image  at  

https://hub.docker.com/_/mono/

Comment: Yes Right It also Support in the Docker I will Try for Mono Runtime

Comment: Is there any option in the Azure Function created in the .net framework version 4.5.2 to adding a docker image.For the Same Project.If is possible means share the Image format ple...

Comment: No sure about it